# Package outline dimensions - meaning of theta and package identification

Tags: packages

When reading data sheet dimensions to create Eagle devices, I've come across a theta (θ) dimension, which seems to indicate the seating angle of a device pin in relation to the pad.

Typically, 0º and 7º θ values are given, and other dimensions can vary significantly for different θ values!

I can't find anything else in the datasheets that would help differentiate these packages - they seem to have the same marking codes.

For instance, the [NX3V1G384](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/NX3V1G384.pdf)

Comment: I'm confused what you're asking. Are you asking if the two different theta values are for different packages? The example you gave is clearly available in SOT353 and SOT886. The theta dimension only applies to the SOT353 package. The SOT886 is leadless.

Comment: Yes, this applies to the SOT353 package. For instance the pin length L(p) is shorter (0.25mm) in the 0º theta package. Are they both NX3V1G384GW?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to be clear what you're asking about:

[image]

The two rows in the dimension table are giving the min and max for each dimension. Theta can be between 0 and 7 degrees. D can be between 1.85 and 2.25 mm. Etc.

There is not necessarily any correlation between one dimension being near its min or max value and another dimension also being near min or max. For example, theta and D are probably not correlated.

On the other hand, others of the dimensions are likely to be correlated. For example, if theta is near 0 degrees, A<sub>1</sub> might also be near its minimum value.

Comment: "The two rows in the dimension table are giving the min and max for each dimension." This makes so much sense. Don't know what led me to think the rows were explicitly correlated.